# How to read raster with libbmp?

Tags: c, bitmap

Yesterday I have downloaded this library:
http://code.google.com/p/libbmp/
They say that this C library is designed for easily reading, writing, and modifying Windows bitmap (BMP) image files. But I could not find any function for reading the bitmap. Does anybody have idea how to read the bitmap (rgb pixels from image) in C? I use CodeBlocks IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reading (load) functionality in that code, so the description is a bit suspect.

I looked at [the code](https://code.google.com/p/libbmp/source/browse/trunk/src/bmpfile.c), and there is no call to `open()` that uses a read mode, and the function `bmp_create()` does not support loading an existing file.

The library seems to be incomplete.

You can have a look at other libraries, perhaps [EasyBMP](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/) (which seems old, but on the other hand so is the BMP format).

Comment: I went to the page of the lib but found no documentation. Do you know where the documentation is?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie No idea, I just browsed the code real quick. It's a single C file.

Comment: EasyBMP is C++ library, I am using C

Answer (score 0):

The following function reads a BMP:

```
char *DIBreadBmp (char *szFilename)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER    *pBmf;
    DWORD               dwBitsSize;
    char                *pDIB;
    int                 fd;

    if ((_sopen_s (&fd, szFilename,(_O_RDONLY|_O_BINARY), _SH_DENYWR,(_S_IREAD|_S_IWRITE))) != 0) {
        LogError (ERR_FILENOTFOUND, szFilename);
        return (0);
    }
    // get length of DIB in bytes for use when reading
    dwBitsSize = _filelength (fd);

    // Go read the DIB file header and check if it's valid.
    pBmf = malloc (sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));

    if ((_read (fd, (LPSTR) pBmf, sizeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER)) != sizeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER))
    ||  (pBmf->bfType != DIB_HEADER_MARKER))
    {
        free(pBmf);
        _close (fd);
        LogError (ERR_NOT_DIB, szFilename);
        return (0);
    }
    // Allocate memory for DIB
    if (!(pDIB= malloc(dwBitsSize - sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER))))
    {
        free(pBmf);
        _close (fd);
        LogError (ERR_MEMORY, szFilename);
        return (0);
    }
    // Go read the bits.
    if (!_read (fd, pDIB, dwBitsSize - sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)))
    {
        free(pDIB);
        free(pBmf);
        _close (fd);
        LogError (ERR_READ, szFilename);
        return (0);
    }
    _close (fd);
    free(pBmf);

    return (pDIB);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for code. I am trying to write some functions to add it to the library. The bitmap.c contains some basic info about bitmap header, so I can try to find the bitmap data. Expecting that the header is made of these: `uint8_t magicNo[2]; uint32_t fsize; uint16_t creator1; uint16_t creator2; uint32_t offset;` the offset is the start of the bitmap pixel data.